# PWA Cookie does not survie restart

Tags: php, cookies, progressive-web-apps

My backend uses PHP. I set a cookie with:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])) 
    error_log('Cookie is available');
else
    error_log('Cookie is not set');

$days = 30;
$expire = time()+60*60*24*$days;
$options = array (
    'expires' => $expire,
    'path' => null,
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    'samesite' => 'Strict'
);
setcookie('cookiename', 'somedata', $options);

if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])) 
    error_log('Cookie is available');
else
    error_log('Cookie is not set');
```

I "install" the PWA via Firefox on Android, but i see the same behavior with Chrome. If i start the PWA from the Homescreen. After the first start, i see in the PHP Logfile:

```
Cookie is not set
Cookie is available
```

After closing the PWA, i start it again. Now i expected something like:

```
Cookie is available
Cookie is available
```

But i get again:

```
Cookie is not set
Cookie is available
```

With that, i assume, the Cookie has not survived the restart. What do i make wrong?

BTW: Using a standard browser application works as expected. The second output is:

```
Cookie is available
Cookie is available
```

Comment: For your info:  PWA = [Progressive Web App](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps). Basically just a website.

Comment: Sure. But the question is, why does the cookie not survive the restart in PWA, but the same site works in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, that information wasn't meant for you, but for the reader of your question. My guess is that the environment in an App doesn't retain its cookies? I don't know much about PWA's, but when I read about data storage cookies aren't mentioned. What they do mention is [web storage](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/assets-and-data?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.dev%2Flearn%2Fpwa%23article-https%3A%2F%2Fweb.dev%2Flearn%2Fpwa%2Fassets-and-data#caches_and_storage), which as good as using a cookie.